# i have error expression expected in angular custom pipe class

Tags: angular

I am creating my custom pipe and I am getting error I don't quite understand:

> ERROR in app/app.sort.ts (1,2): Expr
>   ession expected.
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

My pipe's code:

```
@import { Pipe , PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe ({
    name: 'sort'
})

export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any[], args: string): any {
        if (args === 'ascending') {
            return value.sort();
        } else if (args === 'descending') {
            return value.sort().reverse();
        }
    }
}
```